# Background.js of chrome extension doesn't load when I scroll a web page. What's the issue here?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is entry of background.js from where an insertText() function is called.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      // Handler for .ready() called.

    InsertText();
    });
```

This function call only happens at the first load of the web site. Any subsequent load/change in the web page that I'm currently scrolling, this doesn't get called. Where am I going wrong? Do I've to write a tab change listener for this?

Comment: Er... ready is called when the DOM of the page has loaded, not when it changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to the wrong event. `ready` is triggered when the DOM is loaded, if you want to do something when the page is scrolled, then bind to `scroll`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // code here    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is correct. `$(document).ready` gets called when the DOM is ready, and executes the code within the function: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

This only gets fired once per page, when the page is ready and the DOM is constructed (for the most part, in most browsers).

You can fire actions on specific events, including load. So if you know what content is supposed to be loaded and you want to fire something on it, you can try this (http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#imageID").load(function() {
    // image has loaded
});
```

If you're specifically targeting scroll, you can use the jQuery scroll method: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Beware of how often scroll gets called though, and you may want to delay the event to fire x milliseconds after user has STOPPED scrolling :).

Answer (score 0):

[Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#background_page) Execution and [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#contentScripts) Execution Environments are two different variants, hence some sort of [communication mechanism](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) has to be used

Sample Script to achieve your use case

#### manifest.json

*Registered all parts of chrome extension elements with manifest file*

```
{
"name":"Content to Background Script",
"description":"This Extension invokes background Script function whenever there is a scroll event",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
"permissions":["<all_urls>"] 
}
```

#### background.js

*Registered Event Listeners and functions here*

```
//Some trivial Function
function _someFunction() {
    console.log("I am invoked ...");
}

//Handler when message is sent from Content Scripts
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, caller, handler) {
    if (message["callTo"] == "_someFunction") _someFunction();
});
```

#### myscript.js

*This is a trivial Sample Content Script*

```
//Look for scroll event
document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    console.log("Page is Scrolled hence requesting background page to execute my function");
    //Request Background page for execution of a function
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        "callTo": "_someFunction"
    });
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.